# Interface Builder Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, interface

I have a simple question, yet I have no clue how to resolve it.
I have a form which I've built using [Rapid Interface Builder](https://01.org/rib/online/).
It's a simple form which uses `Jquery Mobile`.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>title</title>

    <script src="lib/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <link href="src/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="src/css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="content">
            <img src="images/Screenshot 2014-04-06 22.png" width="250" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto">

            <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Tenant Issue Log</h1>
                <form action="formSubmit.php" method="POST">
                   <p>
                    <select data-native-menu="false" name="reasonForContact" required>
                        <option>Reason for Contact</option>
                        <option value="Make a Complaint">Make a Complaint</option>
                        <option value="Terminate Contract">Terminate Contract</option>
                        <option value="I Need Assistance">I Need Assistance</option>
                        <option value="Renew Contract">Renew Contract</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <select data-native-menu="false" multiple="multiple" name="assistanceType[]">
                        <option>Assistance Type</option>
                        <option value="Electrical Fault">Electrical Fault</option>
                        <option value="Gas Fault">Gas Fault</option>
                        <option value="Plumbing">Plumbing</option>
                        <option value="Pest">Pest</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p> 
                    <select data-native-menu="false" name="priority">
                        <option>Priority Level</option>
                        <option value="Low">Low</option>
                        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                        <option value="High">High</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <select data-native-menu="false" multiple="multiple" name="areaOfHouse[]">
                        <option>Area of House</option>
                        <option value="Bedroom">Bedroom</option>
                        <option value="Lounge">Lounge/ Living Room</option>
                        <option value="Bathroom">Bathroom</option>
                        <option value="Hallway">Hallway</option>
                        <option value="Kitchen">Kitchen</option>
                        <option value="Garden">Garden</option>
                        <option value="All">All</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <span>Have the local authorities been informed?</span>
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <legend></legend>
                        <input type="radio" id="yes" value="yes" name="autorities">
                        <label for="yes">Yes</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="No" value="no" name="autorities">
                        <label for="No">No</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </p>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" data-theme="d">
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <textarea id="details" name="details">More Details</textarea>
                </div>

                <p><input type="submit" data-role="button" value="Upload Photo of Issue"></p>
                <p><input type="submit" data-role="button" data-theme="b" value="Submit"></p>
            </form>
        </div>
        <a data-role="button" href="http://codeiscool.co.uk" data-theme="b">Make Payment</a>
    </div>         
</div>     
</body>
</html>
```

When I use `GET`, I successfully get the code on my php page, but when I use `POST` I cannot get anything, it simply gives: undefined when I try to do : `var_dump($_POST);`

I really don't see what I'm doing wrong.
Any help will be appreciated.

Here's my php code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 

    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

I don't get anything else but: undefined when I submit the form.
You can see the form on my server right here: http://w3consultation.com/projects/stella9783/

After testing some more, I've realized it's the jquery.mobile that is preventing my form to be sent by POST.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you post some of your logs esp. what does your server say, when you POST the data?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.
It was indeed the Ajax that was preventing the form to submit.

To prevent form submissions from being automatically handled with Ajax, add the data-ajax="false" attribute to the form element. You can also turn off Ajax form handling completely via the ajaxEnabled global config option.